# Having trouble using CSS to nest div's

Tags: html, css

I am using CSS to format the header for my page. I am having trouble getting a `<div>` (the class is `header_button`) to display properly. I am trying to have a static header at the top, with a button inside of it, and on the right. Instead, it is appearing on the right, (in the correct area) except below the header area. First, here are the styles for the header:

```
div.header {
// Used to keep header in the same position on the page
position: fixed;
height: 50px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#191919, #474747); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(#191919, #474747); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#191919, #474747); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(#191919, #474747); 
background-color: black;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 100%;
// Used to keep the header at the top
top: 0px;
}
```

And these are the styles for the div that should go inside of the header.

```
div.header_button {
color: #ccffcc;
border-radius: 10%;
background-color: #3333ff;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: 200;
text-align: center;
padding: 2px;
width: 4%;
text-align: center;
// Used to keep the button almost on the right edge
margin-left: 94%;
}
```

This is the HTML I am using to nest the `header_button` div inside of the `header` itself.

```
<div class="header" >
    <p>
        Testing Text
    </p>
    <div class="header_button">
        Test
    </div>

</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Nx3f/)

Comment: Note `//` doesn't begin a CSS comment. You must use `/* */`. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#comments)

Comment: @Oriol That's interesting. Netbeans IDE seems to highlight it as a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Nx3f/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="header" >
    <div class="header_button">
        Test
    </div>
    <p>
        Testing Text
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.header_button {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I had tried this before, and it didn't work. Oh well, thanks so much. I chose the answer.